# How to forward AngularJS $http response to the browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a backend with header-based authentication and I want to download a file from it. With cookie-based authentication it is simple: you render a link to a file into `<a href...>` and let browser to handle the rest.

I have this code:

```
    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
      // do something
    }, function (response) {
      alert("ERROR");
    });
```

I have injection of HTTP headers, so in this case `$http.get` will populate   them for us. What I want to do is to feed this response to `$window`, so from user perspective it will looks like usual file download.

Is there any way of doing this? Any other options are welcomed.

Comment: If you set the headers properly, you can just set `window.location` (if using a GET) or use a plain form to POST, instead of using ajax.

Comment: @Pointy makes a `very` good argument, I would just like to add/remind you to utilize `$location` or at least `$window.location` instead of just `window.location`

Comment: @Brocco I don't see how/why that would matter; once the HTTP request is initiated, and assuming that the `Content-Disposition` header is set, then none of the client-side software will have any idea that it's even happening.

Comment: @Pointy if he is doing the redirect via angular by doing it via an injected module/component it can be unit tested.

Comment: @Brocco well that's a good point.

Comment: I've added support of access tokens in query strings, so now I can format an appropriate `href`, but I'm still interested if this "integration" is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want is to push the file to the client without them needing to click anything else on the page. You can cause this to occur without needing to mess with $window at all.

Here is an example of how I pushed a zip file created in the browser that contained multiple selected regions of a canvas:

```
var downloader = angular.element('<a>download</a>');
downloader.attr('href', "data:application/zip;base64," + content);
downloader.attr('download', 'my.zip')

var ev = $document[0].createEvent("MouseEvent");
ev.initMouseEvent(
    "click",
    true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
    window, null,
    0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
    false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
    0 /*left*/, null
);
downloader[0].dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: will, this solution looks like a dirty hack. I was looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something but if you are trying to push data to the user you have already downloaded in the app then this is your best bet. This is hackish because what you are doing is hackish. The only way to download a file on the client is to request it, via a click action. If you do not want to user to click something then you need to click it for them.